High CPU, Reads, Writes from Audit Logout
Background
I was given trace logs from SQL Profiler that was run for 15min during a timeframe where we have been experiencing 100% CPU on the server hosting SQL.  I imported those files to a table called TraceTable.  I did find some possible causes that are not related to Audit Logout, however, the top-most result is from Audit Logout and I'd like to understand why the reads / writes / CPU are so high for only 15min.
Research
I read that the duration of Audit Logout is some factor involving the culmination of time, not just the time from the trace time frame.
But I can't find anything to explain the high read / write / cpu, other than some general statements that Audit Logout is usually not the cause of performance issues.  I also found an answer that says the CPU utilization is cumulative like the duration, but the article linked in the answer doesn't explicitly say what the answer says it says.  I would like to verify that this is unrelated to the performance issues we're seeing.
Why does Audit Logout show these concerning stats?
Here is the query I ran:
SELECT TOP 100
  COUNT(*) AS TotalExecutions,     
  EventClass, 
  CAST(TextData as nvarchar(2000)) AS Query ,
  SUM(Duration) AS DurationTotal ,
  SUM(CPU) AS CPUTotal ,
  SUM(Reads) AS ReadsTotal ,
  SUM(Writes) AS WritesTotal
FROM 
  TraceTable
GROUP BY 
  EventClass, 
  CAST(TextData as nvarchar(2000))
ORDER BY 
  CPUTotal DESC

And here is the top result:

(Sorry, I don't have access to the SQL instance so I don't know the exact version. It's safe to assume it's at least 2014, possibly newer)

The Duration, CPU, Reads, etc on Audit: Logout are the totals for the session.  This is clearly documented.
So these totals include all of the values from the other events generated over the course of that session.
